# Wierd symbols after import

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Does anyone know why weird symbols might be showing on our page? 'åÊ'

https://www.vaporshopdirect.com/products/aegis-boost-pod-vape-kit-by-geekvape

We recently exported/imported the product sheet, it runs on Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mangled the encodings. Shopify uses UTF-8 and you might have accidentally converted to ASCII when you edited the file you downloaded. So if you did that, you now have the convert the errors characters back to what they were, or else use the backup of the original export you saved (right?). If you imported your edits Shopify is thus showing what happens when UTF-8 gets converted to ASCII.

Ensure you work in UTF-8 and you will never mangle these characters again. It is still a fairly common error, so no worries, you are not unique there.